# WPF, width of control change with window width change

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, wpf-controls

In WPF application, a grid panel with 3 columns as defined below

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

There is a slider in the second column,the width of the slider needs to reduce when the window width reduces and at some point the slider needs to disappear (kind of responsive design).
I tried naming the second column and binding width of slider to "ActualWidth" property of the column, but it didn't help. 
There is another way to handle window's size change event and do some adjustments. Any other simple way?

---

Update 1 :
Adding more of my code

```
 <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<!-- some other elements in cell 0-->
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1"  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Width="22" Height="22">
                <Image Source="a.png"/>
            </Button>
            <Slider MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="320" Width="320"/>
            <Button Width="22" Height="22" >
                <Image Source="b.png"/>
            </Button>
  <!-- some other elements in cell 2-->
 </StackPanel>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: Share more code please!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the slider is a generic WPF slider control, then simply placing the slider inside the second column should work, as by default the control should fill all available column space. Perhaps a style you have applied to the slider is affecting this functionality? The slider should fill up the column, and shrink down into nothingness as the window/column resizes if you use this code

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Slider Grid.Column='1'></Slider>
</Grid>
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your new code, perhaps this might be more what you are after?

```
<DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <!-- Elements in cell 0-->
    <Grid Width="250" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>

    <!-- Elements in cell 2-->
    <Grid Width="250" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>

    <!-- Cell 1-->
    <DockPanel>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="22" Height="22">
            <Rectangle Fill="Blue"/>
        </Button>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="22" Height="22" >
            <Rectangle Fill="Blue"/>
        </Button>
        <Slider/>
    </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

The slider will resize and disappear accordingly, and the slider position will remain consistent during the resizing of the window

Comment: This case also it is getting cut at the end. Zoom in and observe the right tip end of slider, its open

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `ActualWidth` of a `ColumnDefinition` is not a `DependencyProperty` and `ColumnDefinition` doesn't notify when this property has changed.

Instead try grouping all your controls in column 2 inside a `Grid` and bind to the `ActualWidth` of the grid.

Comment: Added more of my code. I tried to bind to actual width of the stackpanel I have, but didn't work

Comment: That's because the width of the StackPanel is determined by its contents. Put your StackPanel in a Grid and bind to the ActualWidth of the Grid. Should work...

Comment: This didn't help. The slider is showing same fixed size at all window sizes and gone hidden when window size is very small